# Doctrine2: Getting table alrerady exists while using doctrine validate command

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using doctrine 2 in symfony2. Below is my entity file. when I tried to validate schema using below command,

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

I am getting error:

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\sas>php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Sas\SuccessatschoolBundle\Entity\UniversityM
eta' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings Sas\SuccessatschoolBundle\Entity\UniversityMeta#university and Sa
s\SuccessatschoolBundle\Entity\University#metaData are inconsistent with each ot
her.

[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
The table with name 'sas.employer_university_meta' already exists.
```

Here are my entities:
**EmployerMeta**

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="employer_university_meta")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class EmployerMeta extends EmployerUniversityMetaBase
{ }
```

**UniversityMeta**

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="employer_university_meta")
* @ORM\Entity
*/

class UniversityMeta extends EmployerUniversityMetaBase
{ }
```

The purpose of using same table is that both entities have some common fields for employer and university. For that I made a single entity class for common fields and extending the same class in both the entities(employer and university).

This error is coming because when it found the employermeta class to generate schema it creates the table but when it goes to universitymeta class it shows error table already exists.

So, my question is as follows:
Is there any way to resolve this kind of issue without making changes in entity classes? Any help or any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Single Table Inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance.  It allows you to have two different classes mapped to the same table by using a discriminator column,

Comment: use @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE") in entity annotation.